# concurrent access of same window

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, animated-gif

I am using jsf 1.2 with a4j. when any AJAX request is generated GIF animated images are being displayed on the page.

```
    <a4j:status>
<f:facet name="start">
<h:graphicImage  value="/images/ajaxLoading.gif"       
style="float:right;position:absolute;
width:200px;top:100px;left:250px;"/>
</f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

it is all working fine but the requirement is, till the response come if user opens the same URL in new window (Here I am specific to IE8 because IE8 keep same session in new window) then same state of the page or same image should be displayed. But it is not being displayed for my page.

Kindly suggest some solution.......

Answer (score 0):

You status until AJAX response returns is specific to that window/tab.
When you open a new window/tab,though the session would be the same,the new window/tab will have no communication that the AJAX request went in the previous tab,UNLESS we explicitly develop Logic to do so.